# get record by Id XSJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, prepared-statement, hana, hana-xs

I'm new to xsjs, i know to retrieve data from db(HANA db) we need to use prepare statements. I tried using it but any how my .xsjs file is returning me empty JSON. can some one help me? Sharing my code.
Below is user table

```
id | user_name | password | marks
 1 | Prasanna  | test@123 | 10
 2 | sasne     | test@123 | 20
 3 | Ankush    | test@123 | 0
 4 | Shubham   | test@123 | 30
 5 | Anupama   | test@123 | 15
```

Now i want to write get request for accessing data according to `id` requested.
My XSJS code is as follows

```
if ($.request.method === $.net.http.GET) {
var conn = $.db.getConnection();
var id = $.request.parameters.get('id');
var statement = 'SELECT * FROM "USER_TABLE" WHERE ID = ?';
$.response.contentType = "application/json";

try {
    var pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(statement);
    pstmt.setString(1, id);
    var result = pstmt.executeQuery();
    $.response.setBody(JSON.stringify(result));

    $.response.status = $.net.http.OK;

} catch (ex) {
    $.response.setBody(ex.toString());
} finally {
    if (conn) {
        conn.close();
    }
}
}
```

Help will be appriciated

Comment: this code is wriiten in `.xsjs` file, i can't add new tag for this

Comment: Have you tried to debug? Your result is of type $.db. ResultSet. By the way, why you use $.db and not $.hdb which is newer?

Comment: @Rufi i'm new to this .Please provide me better ans to this in answer section. So that i can accept your ans if it is helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just checked it:

```
if ($.request.method === $.net.http.GET) {
    const id = $.request.parameters.get('id');
    $.response.contentType = "application/json";

    const conn = $.hdb.getConnection();
    try {
        const resultSet = conn.executeQuery('select * from "user_table" where "id" = ?', id);
        $.response.setBody(JSON.stringify(resultSet));
        $.response.status = $.net.http.OK;
    } catch (ex) {
        $.response.setBody(ex.toString());
    } finally {
        if (conn) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I think that your problem was that *id* was not in double quotes ("), this is quite important.

As you can see with *hdb* connection it becomes easier and hopefully even faster to handle the sql queries, so use this one instead of db - [link to hdb documentation](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/3de842783af24336b6305a3c0223a369/2.0.01/en-US/$.hdb.Connection.html).

Moreover, use debugger to investigate the issue (I have heard that there are some issues debugging *xsjs* files in Eclipse, but I do it without problems in Intellij IDEA). And yes, I would guess that your `id` is unique thus you could/should get only one row and then `stringify` only `resultSet[0]`.